# Confusion about domains and range (operator in $L^2$)

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose we have bounded linear maps $F:L^2(A) \to L^2(B)$ and $G:L^2(A) \to L^2(A)$.

Let $f \in L^2(B)$ and $u \in L^2(A)$. In fact suppose $f$ is smooth.

Is $fF(G(u)) = F(G(fu))$?

I want to say yes. But what if eg. $L^2(A) \subset L^2(B)$ or vice versa??

Comment: What should $f F(G(u))$ mean? You cannot do pointwise products in $L^2$-space (except trivial cases). Moreover, what should $fu$ mean??

Comment: $fu$ is something like multiplying a function by a constant (from point of view of the function).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro assume $f$ is smooth

Comment: No, I think that you cannot do anything like that. The question is ill-posed, but even if you formulated it correctly it would be false. To wit, observe that in practice, $F$ and $G$ often are integral operators. Then you are basically saying that you can "take a function out of an integral", which as you know is a gross error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking whether the operator $F\circ G$ commutes with the *multiplication operator* $M_f$. This is not true in general. For a  simple example, take $L^2$ on a space with two points, where linear operators are $2\times 2$ matrices, and multiplication operators are precisely the diagonal matrices. Clearly, commutativity fails: 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 &1 \\1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 &0 \\0&2\end{pmatrix} \ne 
\begin{pmatrix}1 &0 \\0&2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1 &1 \\1&1\end{pmatrix} $$
In fact, the following is true: if a matrix commutes with all diagonal matrices, it is itself  diagonal. A general statement is that multiplication operators form a maximal abelian  subalgebra of $B(L^2)$. See [Do we have Maximal Abelian Algebras (MAAs)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/266450/)